# Sound glitch on certain app and system sounds

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've been experiencing an annoying sound glitch since my latest update (update of 23/02/2022 of Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS). Its a periodic buzz which happens when sound is coming out of my headset. The effect is present for system sounds like alert sounds or backspace, for music coming from Spotify and when I'm in a call in Teams-for-linux. Interestingly, the effect is not present on youtube. I can listen to music on youtube (firefox)without any glitch at all but that's about the only place. Here's a copy of the output of sudo lshw -c multimedia:

```
*-usb:1                   
       description: Audio device
       product: Corsair HS45 Surround USB Sound Adapter
       vendor: Corsair
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2
       version: 0.04
       serial: 00000000
       capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
       configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
  *-usb
       description: Video
       product: Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camera (Front F200)
       vendor: Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camera (Front F200)
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2:3
       version: 27.80
       serial: 039150100108
       capabilities: usb-3.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=440mA speed=5000Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:130 memory:d1220000-d1223fff memory:d1200000-d120ffff
```

I have a corsair hs45 headset which is connected via usb (the audio jack is in a usb dongle) which has been working flawlessly for over a year and was plug and play with ubuntu originally. Any one has that issue or any idea how to fix it?
Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have it fixed when I restart the pulseaudio, but before the system restarts.

It looks like this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.13/+bug/1966066

Change Pulse Audio's default sample rate to 48000.

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Find the lines starting with

```
; default-sample-rate
; alternate-sample-rate
```

Remove the ; and change the values to 48000 so it looks like this:

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
```

Save the file
Then restart PulseAudio:

```
systemctl restart --user pulseaudio
```

If that doesn't work then just kill it and it will restart:

```
pulseaudio --kill
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my somewhat similar problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400090/

Comment: Thanks; that solved my "needle scratch" problem every ten seconds or so on YouTube Music/Amazon Music.

Comment: Thanks it solved my earphones making some glitch sounds like aliens talking frequency...