# Annoying 140bpm click/pop sounds, but only at some sound sources

Tags: sound

With many sound sources, at the moment they start to play I get a 140bpm clicking/popping/tapping sound mixed into the output.

- How it sounds

  - Pretty much like the little click you get when you turn on/connect a speaker. Just repeating again and again at exactly 140bpm.
- Where it happens

  - Youtube: never happens.
  - Mp3-files (locally saved, played with various players): always happens.
  - Twitch: sometimes happens, but always on the same stream (stream A will always work and stream B will never work). I checked video/audio codecs of 20 different streams, but while they are a few different ones, I have seen both examples that work and don't work for all of them.
  - System sounds (like the bell sound when you press a key that you shouldn't): always happens.
  - Doesn't matter if I use earphones, external or internal speakers (Thinkpad T460p).
- When it happens

  - Starts at the moment the sound starts to play.
  - When I turn the sound's volume to zero, it persists
  - When I exit the player/close the browser tab, it typically keeps going for about 4 seconds, then stops. Although sometimes it just keeps going indefinitely.
- What I tried (pretty much everything on the first 10 pages of various google searches)

  - Most of the advice I found was changing a bunch of different settings related to automatic standby/shutdown of the sound card.
  - Also tried reinstalling a bunch of audio-related software.

I did my best to avoid posting this question here since it's such a weirdly specific behavior, but at this point it's the only option I have left. In case anyone has any idea what this could be related to, or any tips on how to further diagnose it, I'm grateful for any bit of advice.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1399966/447850) from 12 hours ago in the related sidebar, and it miraculously solved the problem. Since the timing is so close together, maybe the problem is related to some software update (I always do all the updates Ubuntu suggests).